# Using SVM to train my Dataset

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, svm, face-recognition

To understand well the concept behind how  Support Vector Machine works in MATLAB, I advised you to read briefly [THIS VERY IMPORTANT LINK](http://dipwm.blogspot.com/2013/01/svm-support-vector-machine-with-matlab.html).

I am trying to apply the same concept but I have different train set and test set.

For more precision:

**My train set** refers to be named as **C2res{1}** where this last is equal to:

```
 C2res{1} =

           1.0e-05 *

          Columns 1 through 10

            0.5341    0.5822    0.6185    0.7555    0.7369    0.7131    0.5985    0.6483    0.5668    0.6620

          Columns 11 through 12

            0.6523    0.6097
```

**My test set** refers to be named as **C2res{2}** where this last has the same form of C2res{1} but with different values...

Then, I used the concept used in the above link:

```
XTrain = [C2res{1}];
XTest = [C2res{2}];
label = [ones(size(C2res{1},2),1)];
SVMStruct = svmtrain(XTrain , label, 'kernel_function', 'linear');
Group       = svmclassify(SVMStruct, XTest);
```

But unfortunately I always get errors like as:

```
Error using svmtrain (line 335)
Y must contain exactly two groups for method 'SMO'.
```

That is why I need your help please.

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: What errors do you get and where? Please add this to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Buy the way, I updated my answer in the last:)

Comment: @Dan Please can you help me here? thank you a lot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65449934/multi-class-svm-one-vs-one-always-giving-the-same-label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to implement the classification training with two classes? Your `label = [ones(size(C2res{1},2),1)];` contains only one value, and it seems to be expected two values (as two categories). I think that's the reason the error comes out.

If you are applying one-class SVM, try to add such option (see [this page](http://www.openpr.org.cn/files/help/rn01re19.html) for more references on the option):

```
SVMStruct = svmtrain(XTrain , label,'-t 0 -s 2');
```

Comment: Because my Datasets (training and testing images) are all faces images. So I considered that I had only one label and one class. I know that you have great idea about HMAX and how the C2 features are taken :) that is why I am very interested to get your help :):)

Comment: @Christina What output are you expecting? I think you want your classifier judge whether a given dataset is face or not, am i correct? If that's the case you need to use label 1 to represent the face, -1 to represent non-face. And your training set should include those non-face data too

Comment: No, in fact, all my images are faces. But some of them are used as training images and the others as testing. Please I need your opinion about that :)

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error: Error using svmtrain (line 291)
Wrong number of arguments.

Comment: To resolve this problem, do you know an efficient database that contains four directories : 2 directories for facial images (one for training and other for testing), and two directories of non-facial images (one for training and other for testing) ? Please you know such this database I will appreciate very much your help!!

Comment: if you are using the libsvm I recommended you yesterday, try my revision format in the answer. Add the kernel into the option as well.

Comment: Ah yess I downloaded it ;) , so I will try know to use libsvm. So in this case, how to substitute the svmtrain function ? In libsvm, I have svm-train.m. I think that I shoul use svm-train instead of svmtrain

Comment: Try the one in my answer :)

Comment: libsvm. And it is svmtrain, not svm-train. You may need to run the make file first to mex those .c files into the executable matlab files

Comment: did you run the make file in the matlab folder in your libsvm? I suspect you are running the old svm code rather the one you just downloaded.

Comment: I deleted now the old one, and I replace it by the new one. I will run my code now

Comment: That's strange because I can run without error. I think the database for the face is designed to train your model recognize one person's (says Bob)face. So given the face of any person, the model will say whether it is Bob or not. So in your training, +1 will represent all the faces of Bob, while -1 is the faces of others.

Comment: Dear Lennon, do you think that the dataset always must have at least two classes ?

Comment: not necessary. it depends on your problem. See this page for one class svm application:  http://rvlasveld.github.io/blog/2013/07/12/introduction-to-one-class-support-vector-machines/

Comment: Please can you help me here? thank you a lot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65449934/multi-class-svm-one-vs-one-always-giving-the-same-label