# error decrease too slowly on Neural Network BackPropagation Training

Tags: java, backpropagation, neural-network

I tried to implement Neural Network backpropagation using JAVA, I already code it, but the result is unsatifying. the error is decreasing too slow. Below are the example of train result:

```
epoch:1  current error:0.5051166876846451

epoch:2  current error:0.4982484527652138

epoch:3  current error:0.4965995467118879

epoch:4  current error:0.49585659139683363

epoch:5  current error:0.4953426236386938

epoch:6  current error:0.4948766985413233

epoch:7  current error:0.49441754405152294

epoch:8  current error:0.4939551661406868

epoch:9  current error:0.49348601614718984

epoch:10 current error:0.4930078119902486

epoch:11 current error:0.49251846766886453
```

Based on this I started to doubt my code and its algorithm. The activation function used are sigmoid. Below are The sample code of the training.

```
public void learning(int epoch,double learningRateTemp,double desiredErrorTemp,DataSet ds,double momentum){
    int processEpoch=0;
    double sumSquaredError=0;
    DataSetRow dsr;
    Connector conTemp;
    double sumError=0;
    double errorInformation=0;
    double activationValue;
    double partialDerivative;

    do{
        processEpoch++;
        sumSquaredError=0;
        System.out.println("epoch:"+processEpoch);
        //data training set
        for(int a=0;a<ds.countRows();a++){
            dsr=ds.getSpecificRow(a);
            sumError=0;
            double[]input=dsr.getInput();
            double[]output=dsr.getdesiredOutput();
            double sumDeltaInput=0;
            double weightTempValue=0;
            //forward calculation
            this.forwardCalculation(input);               
            //backpropagateofError
            //for output unit

            for(int k=0;k<NeuralLayers[totalLayer-1].getTotalNode();k++){
                activationValue=NeuralLayers[totalLayer-1].getNeuron(k).getValue();
                partialDerivative=(activationValue)*(1-activationValue);
                Neuron Temp=NeuralLayers[totalLayer-1].getNeuron(k);
                errorInformation=(output[k]-Temp.getValue())*partialDerivative;
                Temp.SetErrorInformationTerm(errorInformation);
                sumError+=Math.pow((output[k]-Temp.getValue()),2);
                NeuralLayers[totalLayer-1].setNeuron(k, Temp);
            }
            //end of output unit
             //for hidden Unit
            for(int l=totalLayer-2;l>0;l--){
                for(int j=1;j<NeuralLayers[l].getTotalNode();j++){
                     sumDeltaInput=0;
                     for(int k=0;k<NeuralLayers[l+1].getTotalNode();k++){                                
                       conTemp=NeuralLayers[l+1].getConnector(k, j);
                       if(conTemp.getStatusFrom()==false){
                              weightTempValue=conTemp.getWeight().getValue();
                              sumDeltaInput+=(NeuralLayers[l+1].getNeuron(k).GetErrorInformationTerm()*weightTempValue);
                            }
                        }
                     activationValue=NeuralLayers[l].getNeuron(j).getValue();
                     partialDerivative=(activationValue)*(1-activationValue);
                     errorInformation= sumDeltaInput*partialDerivative;                
                     Neuron neuTemp=NeuralLayers[l].getNeuron(j);
                     neuTemp.SetErrorInformationTerm(errorInformation);
                     NeuralLayers[l].setNeuron(j, neuTemp);
                     }
                }
            updateWeight(learningRateTemp,momentum);
            sumSquaredError+=sumError;            
            }       
    sumSquaredError/=(double)(ds.countRows()*NeuralLayers[totalLayer-1].getTotalNode());
    sumSquaredError=Math.sqrt(sumSquaredError);
    System.out.println("current error:"+sumSquaredError);
    } while(processEpoch<epoch && sumSquaredError>desiredErrorTemp);
}
```

}

for the forward calculation

```
private void forwardCalculation(double[] inputValue){
        Connector Contemp;
        double SumNodeWeight=0;
        int start=1;
        int count=0;
        setNodeValue(inputValue,0);
        do{
            count++;
            if("output".equals(NeuralLayers[count].statusLayer))
                     start=0;
                else start=1;
           //get sum of all input  
            for(int j=start;j<NeuralLayers[count].getTotalNode();j++){
                for(int i=0;i<NeuralLayers[count].sizeConnector(j);i++){
                    Contemp=NeuralLayers[count].getConnector(j, i);
                    SumNodeWeight+=Contemp.getCombinedweightInput();
                }
                SumNodeWeight=(1/(1+Math.exp(-SumNodeWeight)));
                NeuralLayers[count].setNeuronValue(j, SumNodeWeight); 
                SumNodeWeight=0;
            }
    }while(!"output".equals(NeuralLayers[count].statusLayer));
 }
```

and to update the weights

```
private void updateWeight(double learningRateTemp,double momentum){
    double newWeight;
    double errorInformation;
    Connector conTemp;
    for(int LayerPosition=totalLayer-1;LayerPosition>0;LayerPosition--){
        for(int node=1;node<NeuralLayers[LayerPosition].getTotalNode();node++){
            errorInformation=NeuralLayers[LayerPosition].getNeuron(node).GetErrorInformationTerm();
                //for bias weight
                newWeight=learningRateTemp*errorInformation;
                conTemp=NeuralLayers[LayerPosition].getConnector(node, 0);
                conTemp.updateWeight(newWeight,false,0);
                NeuralLayers[LayerPosition].updateConnector(conTemp, node, 0);
                /////////////////////
                //for other node weight
                for(int From=1;From<NeuralLayers[LayerPosition].sizeConnector(node);From++){
                    conTemp=NeuralLayers[LayerPosition].getConnector(node, From);
                    double weightCorrection=learningRateTemp*errorInformation*NeuralLayers[LayerPosition-1].getNeuron(From).getValue();
                    conTemp.updateWeight(weightCorrection,true,momentum);
                    NeuralLayers[LayerPosition].updateConnector(conTemp,node,From);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

am I on the right Track? I already searched for the bugs in few days, and it still nothing. Does my formula to calculate the error is correct? thank you very much!

Comment: What is the value of learning rate and momentum?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not any kind of expert on this, nor Java programming, but It might be affecting, you put you variable `sumError` declared as `0` at the beggining, then you add the error from the outputs, and then in the for cycle of the hidden layers it appears again added to `sumSquaredError` variable, but if you are going to calc the error of training, why is it inside the "hidden layer cucle"?

```
for(int l=totalLayer-2;l>0;l--){ 
    for(int j=1;j<NeuralLayers[l].getTotalNode();j++){

    }
    updateWeight(learningRateTemp,momentum);
    sumSquaredError+=sumError;
}
```

Shouldn't it be outside?

I´ll make reference to the pseudocode of someone who answered me before.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976452/whats-is-the-difference-between-train-validation-and-test-set-in-neural-networ)

Hope this helps!