# MATLAB Neural Network Performance data structures

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am approximating a cosine function using a neural network on MATLAB. When training is finished, a number of data structures are outputted on the workspace. Amongst these are 4 structures (well, values really) which contain the performance results of the network.

For the performance analysis, you get a *performance* structure, *trainPerformance*, *testPerformance* and *valPerformance*.

While I know what the last three structures mean, the first one is confusing me as it is a different value than the others.

I'm using the Neural Network Toolbox.

```
% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);

% Test the Network
outputs = net(inputs);
errors = gsubtract(targets,outputs);
performance = perform(net,targets,outputs)

% Recalculate Training, Validation and Test Performance
trainTargets = targets .* tr.trainMask{1};
valTargets = targets  .* tr.valMask{1};
testTargets = targets  .* tr.testMask{1};
trainPerformance = perform(net,trainTargets,outputs)
valPerformance = perform(net,valTargets,outputs)
testPerformance = perform(net,testTargets,outputs)
```

What is the difference between the *performance* structure and the other three?

I think I just realised that the performance is the overall result of the network, and the trainPerformance is for the current iteration.

Comment: An answer is likely to be specific to the library you are using. There are several options in Matlab. To help clarify what you are seeing, please say which module/lib you are using for NNs, and give the line of code that trains and returns the structures.

Comment: Okay re-edited the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While doing Neural Networks you usually take your data and divide it into 3 subsets: *Training*, *Validation* and *Test*. Someone has a quite good questiond and answer in this site about what these are and why:

[whats is the difference between train, validation and test set, in neural networks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976452/whats-is-the-difference-between-train-validation-and-test-set-in-neural-networ)

In your case, It looks like you test the performance in each of these subsets of your data **and in the whole set of data also!** Therefore, `performance` is the performance of the NN using all data, and `train/val/test-performance` are the performance for each of the mentioned subsets of data.

Make sure you understand properly what these 3 subsets are, as it is crucial for understanding the performance of your NN

Comment: As I said, I understand what the train/val/test-performance values are, however I was unsure about the performance value.

Thank you for your answer now I understand!