# How to fix overfitting in Elman neural network?

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, recurrent-neural-network

I'm training elman network with neurolab python library and my net doesn't work properly.

- Training input vectors: http://pastebin.com/urQX2eEA
- Training target vector: http://pastebin.com/1JQh1xZv
- Sample vector to test a network: http://pastebin.com/jprZhBHa

But while training it is showing too big errors:

```
Epoch: 100; Error: 23752443150.672318;
Epoch: 200; Error: 284037904.0305649;
Epoch: 300; Error: 174736152.57367808;
Epoch: 400; Error: 3318952.136089243;
Epoch: 500; Error: 299017.4471083774;
Epoch: 600; Error: 176600.0906688521;
Epoch: 700; Error: 176599.32080188877;
Epoch: 800; Error: 185178.21132511366;
Epoch: 900; Error: 177224.2950528976;
Epoch: 1000; Error: 176632.86797784362;
The maximum number of train epochs is reached
```

As a result network fails on testing sample.
Original MICEX:

```
1758,97
1626,18
1688,34
1609,19
1654,55
1669
1733,17
1642,97
1711,53
1771,05
```

Predicted MICEX:

```
[ 1237.59155306]
 [ 1237.59155306]
 [ 1237.59155306]
 [ 1237.59155306]
 [ 1237.59155306]
 [ 1237.59155306]
 [ 1237.59155306]
 [ 1237.59155306]
 [ 1237.59155306]
 [ 1237.59155306]
```

Here is my code:

```
import neurolab as nl
import numpy as np

# Create train samples
MICEX = [421.08,455.44,430.3,484,515.17,468.85,484.73,514.71,551.72,591.09,644.64,561.78,535.4,534.84,502.81,549.28,611.03,632.97,570.76,552.22,575.74,635.38,598.04,593.88,603.89,639.98,700.65,784.28,892.5,842.52,944.55,1011,1171.44,1320.83,1299.19,1486.85,1281.5,1331.39,1380.24,1448.72,1367.24,1426.83,1550.71,1693.47,1656.97,1655.19,1698.08,1697.28,1570.34,1665.96,1734.42,1677.02,1759.44,1874.73,1850.64,1888.86,1574.33,1660.42,1628.43,1667.35,1925.24,1753.67,1495.33,1348.92,1027.66,731.96,611.32,619.53,624.9,666.05,772.93,920.35,1123.38,971.55,1053.3,1091.98,1197.2,1237.18,1284.95,1370.01,1419.42,1332.64,1450.15,1436.04,1332.62,1309.31,1397.12,1368.9,1440.3,1523.39,1565.52,1687.99,1723.42,1777.84,1813.59,1741.84,1666.3,1666.59,1705.18,1546.05,1366.54,1498.6,1499.62,1402.02,1510.91,1594.32,1518.29,1474.14,1312.24,1386.89,1406.36,1422.38,1459.01,1423.46,1405.19,1477.87,1547.18,1487.46,1440.02,1386.69,1343.99,1331.24,1377.6,1364.54,1463.13,1509.62,1479.35,1503.39,1454.05,1444.71,1369.29,1306.01,1432.03,1476.38,1379.61,1400.71,1411.07,1488.47,1533.68,1396.61,1647.69]

Brent = [26.8,28.16,28.59,30.05,28.34,27.94,28.76,30.48,29.51,33.01,32.36,35.12,36.98,33.51,41.6,39.33,47.08,48.78,44.03,40.24,45.87,50.14,53.05,49.33,49.83,54.85,59.7,66.68,62.56,58.35,53.41,58.87,65.43,60.05,64.94,72,69,73.28,75.16,69.64,61.37,56.97,64.42,60.13,57.21,60.66,68.42,67.28,68.82,73.26,78.05,73.53,81.75,91.14,88,93.85,91.98,100.04,100.51,112.71,128.27,140.3,123.96,115.17,98.96,65.6,53.49,45.59,45.93,45.84,48.68,50.64,65.8,69.42,71.52,69.32,68.92,75.09,78.36,77.93,71.18,78.03,82.17,87.35,74.6,74.66,78.26,74.42,82.11,83.26,85.45,94.59,100.56,112.1,117.17,126.03,116.68,111.8,117.54,114.49,102.15,109.19,110.37,107.22,111.16,123.04,122.8,119.47,101.62,97.57,104.62,114.92,112.14,108.4,111.17,111.11,114.56,111,109.89,101.74,100.15,101.5,107.7,114.45,108.2,108.9,110.11,110.9,105.79,108.65,107.7,108.14,109.49,112.4,105.52,103.11,94.8,85.96,68.34,57.54,52.95]
DJIA = [8850.26,8985.44,9233.8,9415.82,9275.06,9801.12,9782.46,10453.92,10488.07,10583.92,10357.7,10225.57,10188.45,10435.48,10139.71,10173.92,10080.27,10027.47,10428.02,10783.01,10489.94,10766.23,10503.76,10192.51,10467.48,10274.97,10640.91,10481.6,10568.7,10440.07,10805.87,10717.5,10864.86,10993.41,11109.32,11367.14,11168.31,11150.22,11185.68,11381.15,11679.07,12080.73,12221.93,12463.15,12621.69,12268.63,12354.35,13062.91,13627.64,13408.62,13211.99,13357.74,13895.63,13930.01,13371.72,13264.82,12650.36,12266.39,12262.89,12820.13,12638.32,11350.01,11378.02,11543.96,10850.66,9325.01,8829.04,8776.39,8000.86,7062.93,7608.92,8168.12,8500.33,8447,9171.61,9496.28,9712.28,9712.73,10344.84,10428.05,10067.33,10325.26,10856.63,11008.61,10136.63,9774.02,10465.94,10014.72,10788.05,11118.49,11006.02,11577.51,11891.93,12226.34,12319.73,12810.54,12569.79,12414.34,12143.24,11613.53,10913.38,11955.01,12045.68,12217.56,12632.91,12952.07,13212.04,13213.63,12393.45,12880.09,13008.68,13090.84,13437.13,13096.46,13025.58,13104.14,13860.58,14054.49,14578.54,14839.8,15115.57,14909.6,15499.54,14810.31,15129.67,15545.75,16086.41,16576.66,15698.85,16321.71,16457.66,16580.84,16717.17,16826.6,16563.3,17098.45,17042.9,17390.52,17828.24,17823.07,17164.95]
CAC_40 = [2991.75,3084.1,3210.27,3311.42,3134.99,3373.2,3424.79,3557.9,3638.44,3725.44,3625.23,3674.28,3669.63,3732.99,3647.1,3594.28,3640.61,3706.82,3753.75,3821.16,3913.69,4027.16,4067.78,3908.93,4120.73,4229.35,4451.74,4399.36,4600.02,4436.45,4567.41,4715.23,4947.99,5000.45,5220.85,5188.4,4930.18,4965.96,5009.42,5165.04,5250.01,5348.73,5327.64,5541.76,5608.31,5516.32,5634.16,5930.77,6104,6054.93,5751.08,5662.7,5715.69,5841.08,5667.5,5614.08,4871.8,4790.66,4707.07,4996.54,5014.28,4425.61,4392.36,4485.64,4027.15,3487.07,3262.68,3217.97,2962.37,2693.96,2803.94,3159.85,3273.55,3138.93,3426.27,3657.72,3794.96,3601.43,3684.75,3936.33,3737.19,3708.8,3974.01,3816.99,3507.56,3442.89,3643.14,3476.18,3715.18,3833.5,3610.44,3804.78,4005.5,4110.35,3989.18,4106.92,4006.94,3980.78,3672.77,3256.76,2981.96,3242.84,3154.62,3159.81,3298.55,3447.94,3423.81,3212.8,3005.48,3196.65,3291.66,3413.07,3354.82,3429.27,3557.28,3641.07,3732.6,3723,3731.42,3856.75,3948.59,3738.91,3992.69,3933.78,4143.44,4299.89,4295.21,4295.95,4165.72,4408.08,4391.5,4487.39,4519.57,4422.84,4246.14,4381.04,4426.76,4233.09,4390.18,4263.55,4604.25]
SSEC = [1576.26,1486.02,1476.74,1421.98,1367.16,1348.3,1397.22,1497.04,1590.73,1675.07,1741.62,1595.59,1555.91,1399.16,1386.2,1342.06,1396.7,1320.54,1340.77,1266.5,1191.82,1306,1181.24,1159.15,1060.74,1080.94,1083.03,1162.8,1155.61,1092.82,1099.26,1161.06,1258.05,1299.03,1298.3,1440.22,1641.3,1672.21,1612.73,1658.64,1752.42,1837.99,2099.29,2675.47,2786.34,2881.07,3183.98,3841.27,4109.65,3820.7,4471.03,5218.82,5552.3,5954.77,4871.78,5261.56,4383.39,4348.54,3472.71,3693.11,3433.35,2736.1,2775.72,2397.37,2293.78,1728.79,1871.16,1820.81,1990.66,2082.85,2373.21,2477.57,2632.93,2959.36,3412.06,2667.74,2779.43,2995.85,3195.3,3277.14,2989.29,3051.94,3109.11,2870.61,2592.15,2398.37,2637.5,2638.8,2655.66,2978.83,2820.18,2808.08,2790.69,2905.05,2928.11,2911.51,2743.47,2762.08,2701.73,2567.34,2359.22,2468.25,2333.41,2199.42,2292.61,2428.49,2262.79,2396.32,2372.23,2225.43,2103.63,2047.52,2086.17,2068.88,1980.12,2269.13,2385.42,2365.59,2236.62,2177.91,2300.59,1979.21,1993.8,2098.38,2174.66,2141.61,2220.5,2115.98,2033.08,2056.3,2033.31,2026.36,2039.21,2048.33,2201.56,2217.2,2363.87,2420.18,2682.83,3234.68,3210.36]


Brent_sample = [62.48, 55.1, 66.8, 65.19, 63.14, 51.85, 53.12, 48.44, 49.5, 44.5]
DJIA_sample = [18132.7, 17776.12, 17840.52, 18010.68, 17619.51, 17689.86, 16528.03, 16284.7, 17663.54, 17719.92]
CAC_40_sample = [4922.99, 5031.47, 5042.84, 5084.08, 4812.24, 5081.73, 4652.34, 4453.91, 4880.18, 4951.83]
SSEC_sample = [3310.3, 3747.9, 4441.66, 4611.74, 4277.22, 3663.73, 3205.99, 3052.78, 3382.56, 3445.4]



MICEX = np.asarray(MICEX)
Brent = np.asarray(Brent)
DJIA = np.asarray(DJIA)
CAC_40 = np.asarray(CAC_40)
SSEC = np.asarray(SSEC)

Brent_sample = np.asarray(Brent_sample)
DJIA_sample = np.asarray(DJIA_sample)
CAC_40_sample = np.asarray(CAC_40_sample)
SSEC_sample = np.asarray(SSEC_sample)

size = len(MICEX)

inp = np.vstack((Brent, DJIA, CAC_40, SSEC)).T
tar = MICEX.reshape(size, 1)
smp = np.vstack((Brent_sample, DJIA_sample, CAC_40_sample, SSEC_sample)).T

# Create network with 2 layers and random initialized
net = nl.net.newelm(
        [[min(inp[:, 0]), max(inp[:, 0])],
         [min(inp[:, 1]), max(inp[:, 1])],
         [min(inp[:, 2]), max(inp[:, 2])],
         [min(inp[:, 3]), max(inp[:, 3])]
         ],
        [46, 1],
        [nl.trans.TanSig(), nl.trans.PureLin()]  # SatLinPrm(0.00000001, 421.08, 1925.24)
                )
# Set initialized functions and init
net.layers[0].initf = nl.init.InitRand([-0.1, 0.1], 'wb')
net.layers[1].initf = nl.init.InitRand([-0.1, 0.1], 'wb')
net.init()

# Changing training method
# net.trainf = nl.train.train_cg

# Train network
error = net.train(inp, tar, epochs=1000, show=100, goal=0.02)

# Simulate network
out = net.sim(smp)
print(smp)
print('MICEX predictions for the next 10 periods:\n', out)
```

Does anybody know a solution of this problem?

Comment: I don't see any errors.  What isn't working?  The error is getting smaller so it appears to be working.  Another thing to notice is that the error stops getting smaller, it appears that you're [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) your training set, and it's not going to generalize well.

Comment: @john-carpenter Thanks! And how can I fix this overfitting in my case?

Comment: there are a few methods, one is to detect that your error isn't going down anymore on your training set and stop training.  The other is to use a validation set, that you don't train with, but still measure the error.  When the error rate on the validation set stops decreasing, then you stop.  [Here's an SO link for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976452/whats-is-the-difference-between-train-validation-and-test-set-in-neural-networ)

Comment: @john-carpenter Thanks a lot! I will try!

Comment: I would also try normalizing the inputs somehow so that they are all on the same scale. That will help the network learn better.

Comment: @Aaron , The main problem is that all output data is the same:

        1243.34142113,
        1243.34142113....10 times ]

I have tried a suggestion (from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/improve-neural-network-generalization-and-avoid-overfitting.html#bss4gz0-38)) to regularize network  with following [code](http://pastebin.com/FqwRkwCs)
If you get this comment, please reply.

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is **not overfitting**. You are **underfitting**, you do not even converge for training cases. Can't you just increase number of epochs? Let the net converge.

Comment: I have just used 10000 epochs with following configuration:
 - 25 neurons
 - elman network type.Network code: http://pastebin.com/GYM2E0ci
Script log: http://pastebin.com/5AJbvXME
as you can see, error still stops at near 1766.00
And the output is the same for all 10 rows...